# How to show validation errors in view using redirect in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

- 

I try different methods but it's not working.
My question is how can achieve both these requirements: passing validation data and pass my data which I get from the database
*

```
<?php
class Jobpost extends my_controller {  
  function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->helper(array('html','url'));   

}


 function index()
{  
     $this->load->model('new_post','model');
     $ans= $this->model->get_user_data();
     $this->load->view('website/job_post',['ans'=>$ans]);
  
}
public function new_post()
{
    if ($this->form_validation->run('post') == FALSE)
    {
      $this->index(); /* index function above. */
    }
    else
    {
        echo "succes";
    }
}}?

         <div class=" text-center">
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You could pass the `validation_errors()` through `flashdata` (requires sessions to be loaded). It has minimal overhead and can be incorporated in all views with an `if` block. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the error messages as flashdata. This works with the session library.

It can be implemented as follows

In your controller:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('Failure', 'failure message.');
redirect("To your view");
```

In the View

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('Failure')){ ?>
$('.confirm-div').html('<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('Failure'); ?>').show();
<?php } ?>
```